# mysql procedure parameter and FIND_IN_SET performance

Tags: mysql

I have a table with over 1 MIO rows and I like to create a stored procedure instead of calling a direct sql statement, but I have performance issues with the FIND_IN_SET function.

Start from the scratch:
My existing query is:

```
SELECT id 
FROM `tablex`
WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3;
```

The WHERE clause is built by PHP form a previous result. Its much more complex as here in this example .-).

This query works fine for me and I´m happy with the performance.

Now want to create a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FOO`(**IN `p_ids` VARCHAR(255)**)
```

The p_ids are comma separated and this is running but very slow, because FIND_IN_SET is not
using the index on the ids.

```
SELECT id
FROM `tablex`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,p_ids)
```

I like to find a way to get the complete WHERE clause from my first query into the stored procedure, or to find a faster solution as the Find_in_set thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PREPARE` to create dynamic SQL.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id FROM tablex WHERE id in (', p_ids, ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: When I add your suggestion into my MySQL Workbench where I have open the procedure:

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FOO`(IN `p_ids` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id FROM tablex WHERE id in (', p_ids, ')';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END

I will get the following error: CONCAT is not valid on this positon, excepting a complete function call or other expressions.

I´,m complete new in the procedure writing, so I have no idea where I should place the CONCAT function.

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, the formatting is lost. If it's not working, add the code to the question.

Comment: Ahh, I found it. The closing breaket was missing. But the error message can be written a little bit clearer .-)

Answer (score 0):

no code in comments :-)
Here are the syntax corrected version.

SQL CALL:

```
CALL `db`.`FOO`("2,3,4");
```

Procedure CODE:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FOO`(IN `p_ids` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id FROM tablex WHERE id in (', p_ids, ')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```